# How to playback TRM (US Court Audio Record) files?

Tags: sound, vlc, codecs, file-format, playback

I have files with TRM/TRS extensions (US Court Audio/Video Records) that I need to playback. VLC was able to playback the video but does not recognise the audio codec.

The error message reads: `Unidentified codec: VLC could not identify the audio or video codec`

How can I playback those files on Ubuntu?

Update:

I used MediaInfo to get more information on the audio:

```
Audio
ID                                       : 0
Format                                   : 4180
Codec ID                                 : 4180
```

The right click in the file explore gives the following audio codec: `audio/x-avi-unknown`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is a rather peculiar audio codec. Your best bet is to:

1. Use [FTR Webplayer](https://www.fortherecord.com/products/ftrwebplayer/)
2. Try to install FTR player from [the same site](https://www.fortherecord.com/products/ftr-player/) through Wine.

Comment: This did not fix the issue. VLC still reports `Unidentified codec:
VLC could not identify the audio or video codec`

Comment: Seems to me its a VLC issue and maybe ask them?

Comment: Find one of the files in the file manager, right-click, properties, audio tab and check the audio codec mentioned there.

Comment: @ToDo I got `audio/x-avi-unknown`, I added more info to my question.

Comment: https://www.file-extensions.org/trm-file-extension-court-record-audio-format

Comment: See edited answer.